# Flutter 3.0 Opacity Optimizations

Tags: flutter, performance, animation, rendering, opacity

In this [Flutter 3.0 changes blog post](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-8c74a5bc32d0), it’s noted that “We have [further improved](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/30957) the performance of opacity animations in simple cases. In particular, when an Opacity widget contains only **a single rendering primitive**, the saveLayer method…”. From reading the linked GitHub issue as well, it’s not clear to me what a “single rendering primitive” means. Is anyone here able to clarify and also shed light on when / how developers can take advantage of this optimization? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this was not a developer friendly optimization and speaks more to future optimizations that can be expected for developers to take advantage of.

https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/30957#issuecomment-1185758069

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).